# Is it possible to export a function to dll that has a function as a paremeter?

Tags: c++, dll

Is it possible to export a function to dll that has a function as a paremeter?

What are the limitations to what I can export/import to dll?

Comment: What do you mean by _"has a function as a paremeter"_? Do you mean a function _pointer_? That's completely legal.

Comment: yes, that is what I mean

Answer (score 0):

You can export a function that takes a function pointer as a parameter.  You should specify the calling convention on the parameter to avoid some strange, hard to debug errors.